# How to Store Values from Select2 SelectList as String

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

Not sure how to word this so bare with me. So I am currently using select2 with my check out system Im making. The idea is that on the form to checkout someone can use the select list (with select2) to checkout multiple items at once and I want these items to be stored in a string in the database. It loads fine but when I try to submit the form it returns an error because its returning null and cant get the values as strings. Not sure what to do. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Heres what I have so far:

Model Class and View Model:

```
    public class CheckedOutItem
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Department { get; set; }

        public string Role { get; set; }

        public string Items{ get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string[] SelectedItems { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt}")]
        [Display(Name = "Date Checked Out")]
        public DateTimeOffset DateCheckedOut { get; set; }
            = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public class CheckOutItemVM
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Department { get; set; }

        public string Role { get; set; }

        public string Items{ get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string[] SelectedItems { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Checked Out")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt}")]
        public DateTimeOffset DateCheckedOut { get; set; }
            = DateTime.Now;

        public CheckOutItem GetCheckOuttInstance()
        {
            return new CheckOutItem
            {
                Id = 0,
                UserId = this.UserId,
                FirstName = this.FirstName,
                LastName = this.LastName,
                Items = this.Items,
                Department = this.Department,
                Role= this.Role,
                DateCheckedOut = this.DateCheckedOut,
                SelectedItems = this.SelectedItems,
            };
        }

    }
```

In Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult CheckOutItems()
        {
            ViewBag.ItemId= new SelectList(_itemRepo.ReadItemList(), "Id", "Name");
            return View();
        }

[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult CheckOutItems(CheckOutItemVM itemVM)
        {
            var checkout = itemVM.GetCheckOuttInstance();


            var itemsToCheckout = new CheckOutItemVM
            {
                UserId = checkout.UserId,
                FirstName = checkout.FirstName,
                LastName = checkout.LastName,
                Department = checkout.Department,
                Role = checkout.Role,
                DateCheckedOut = checkout.DateCheckedOut,
                SelectedItems = checkout.SelectedItems,
                Items = checkout.Items
            };

            _itemRepo.CheckOutItems(checkout);

            RedirectToAction("CheckOutItems", "Item");
            //ModelState.Clear();

            return View(itemsToCheckout);
        }
```

In View:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var items = $(".itemSelect").select2();
    });
</script>

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CheckOutItems">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label">User ID</label>
                <input id="UserId" asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FullName" class="control-label">Full Name</label>
                <input id="FullName" asp-for="FullName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Department" class="control-label"></label>
               <input id="Department" asp-for="Department" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Department" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Role" class="control-label">Role</label>
               <input id="Role" asp-for="Role" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Role" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Items" class="control-label">Items</label>
                <select asp-for="Items" class="itemSelect form-control" name="items" multiple asp-items="ViewBag.ItemId">
                    <option value="Select Items(s) To Checkout" disabled></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DateCheckedOut" class="control-label" hidden></label>
                <input asp-for="DateCheckedOut" class="form-control" hidden />
                <span asp-validation-for="DateCheckedOut" class="text-danger" hidden></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Check Out" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
    <script src="~/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/select2/js/select2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You can try to use `public string[] Items { get; set; }` or `public List<string> Items { get; set; }` as `T. van Schagen` said.

Result:
[image]
2.Or you can still use  `public string Items{ get; set; }`,use js to save data to a hidden input before form posting.Here is a demo:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="CheckOutItems">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label">User ID</label>
                    <input id="UserId" asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="FullName" class="control-label">Full Name</label>
                    <input id="FullName" asp-for="FullName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Department" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input id="Department" asp-for="Department" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Department" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Role" class="control-label">Role</label>
                    <input id="Role" asp-for="Role" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Role" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Items" class="control-label">Items</label>
                    <select asp-for="Items" class="itemSelect form-control" name="itemss" multiple asp-items="ViewBag.ItemId">
                        <option value="Select Items(s) To Checkout" disabled></option>
                    </select>
                    <input hidden name="Items" id="newItem"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DateCheckedOut" class="control-label" hidden></label>
                    <input asp-for="DateCheckedOut" class="form-control" hidden />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DateCheckedOut" class="text-danger" hidden></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Check Out" class="btn dhl-button" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>
@section Scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var items = $(".itemSelect").select2();
    });
    $("form").submit(function ()
    {
        $("#newItem").val($("#Items").val().toString());
    })
</script>
   
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Doing the hidden input before posting worked like a charm. Idk why using an array or list just wouldnt work but Im glad to be past this now. Thank you!

Comment: so this does what I want it to but now Im facing another challenge. If I want to be able to check in equipment in my system the way I have it currently setup is to read the item from that string and once its checked in delete it from the checked out list but with the string being two in one (ex: "1", "2") I cant seem to do that. Any advice on how to go about getting "2" from that string and removing after its not needed? This is why a list would probably be easier I just cant get seem to figure out why using a list in my setup always returns null

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what i was doing wrong was the `name="items"` it needs to be `name="items[]"`. Give it a try

Comment: Thank you for this advice. That did fix the issue of it not submitting without throwing an error but the values are still not being passed to the controller and stored where I need them to be. Any more suggestions?

Comment: they dont ''arrive'' in the controller? you sure you calling them the right way?

Comment: var checkout = itemVM.GetCheckOuttInstance();

            string joinItems = "";

            foreach(var i in checkout.SelectedItems)
            {
                joinItems = string.Join(',', i);
            }

Comment: var itemsToCheckout = new CheckOutItemsVM
            {
                UserId = checkout.UserId,
                FirstName = checkout.FirstName,
                LastName = checkout.LastName,
                Department = checkout.Department,
                Role = checkout.Role,
                DateCheckedOut = checkout.DateCheckedOut,
                SelectedItems = checkout.SelectedItems,
                Items = string.Join(',',checkout.SelectedItems.ToString())
            };

            _itemRepo.CheckOutItems(checkout);

Comment: That is what i tried in my controller to fetch them and tbh I dont think I did it right at all. This is my 3rd attempt of trying. it still returns null

Answer (score 0):

Your 'items' property is a string. A multi-select in a form uses a collection and adds each item you select to the collection of specified in `asp-for`. Therefore the property in your model should be a collection type (for example `string[]`). Then in your controller you can join the items to a string and save that to the database.

Comment: After changing it to a string[] or even a list and joining them it still doesnt return anything. I put a breakpoint on it and it says that its still returning null. Not sure why

Comment: do you have any more suggestions? I really appreciate the help

Comment: Have you assured your select list is correctly loaded in your view?